# Preventing a predesigned tab in a TabControl from loading

Tags: .net, user-interface, tabcontrol

Forgive the probably silly question - I'm not used to working with GUIs.

I've got a TabControl that's been prebuilt in the designer. There are many tabs, but only certain ones need to show up based on a variable at the time of loading the form. I originally tried using the Remove command on the FormLoad to remove the unneeded tabs, but because there are multiple tabs with multiple additional objects in each tab, they visibly load and then disappear and it's rather ugly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Remove` in the form constructor, right after `InitializeComponents`. That happens way before the form is shown.

Comment: This did it. I actually just placed a case statement for the loading of each tab so it won't even load what's not needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Design your tabs contents as usercontrols. On the main form, each tab only contains a single control. If you want load-on-demand, then make tabs empty in the designer, and put the corresponding usercontrol in the tab when it's first shown.

Comment: So for each unique tab, create a new user control. When I load the form, I can add a new tab and just place the appropriate user control on it and be done? I'll give it a shot. Worries me a bit because there's so much code for each, but i'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: If the tabs are independent, then it's actually a good thing if you separate them in different controls.